# WP7 how to rate a Song

Tags: windows-phone-7, rate, audio-player

I see that the [Song class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.xna.framework.media.song.aspx) only contains `IsRated` and `Rating` property with Set method.
However, I see that the default music player application in WP7 has the ability to rate a song

So, how can I rate a Song ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both Rating and IsRated are only get methods. 
This means you can get the value of the rating but you can't set it.

That can only be done by the default media player

For Rating
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.xna.framework.media.song.rating.aspx

For IsRated
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.xna.framework.media.song.israted.aspx

As you can see both only have get methods

Comment: it seems that the default media player has more capabilities than 3rd app ?